# IntelliJ is hiding folder in project window mentioned in .gitignore file, how to show that folder in project window?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ project window and .gitignore file snapshot]

- ignoring build folder does not show it in project window.
- commenting .gradle in .gitignore does show it in project windows.

I want to show both .gradle and build folders in project windows but I also want to include them in .gitignore file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Right click on a directory in the project view and make sure **Hide ignored files** option is not enabled.

This feature is provided by a third-party [.ignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) plug-in. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't hide ignored files out of the box.

**Note:** If you don't see the .gitignore-d files, then try clicking this option regardless of its label in this menu. Sometimes because of a bug the entry says "hide" but clicking it actually **shows** the hidden files.

[image: hide]

Comment: My WebStorm doesn't have this option :((

Comment: You should install  .ignore plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Some updates to **.ignore** plugin suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398007/2915738).
IntelliJ now suggests installing [foldable-projectview](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17288-foldable-projectview)

This plugin really provides flexible configuration options.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin does not support hiding based on an existing `.gitignore` (https://github.com/hsz/intellij-foldable-projectview/issues/4).