# IntellijIDE hide target folder if add it to .gitignore

Tags: git, intellij-idea, target

I add target folder to .gitignore file and this folder hide. I need show target when it in .gitignore. In IntellijIDE I have enable "`show excluded files`"

How can I show it?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398007/104891 help?

Comment: yes! coooool! Thank you